# Cannot parse json using Jackson in Kotlin

Tags: json, jackson, kotlin

I have the next json returned from server

```
{"s":2,"v":[[{"g":"value"},{"s":"value"},{"t":"value"}],[{"g":"value"},{"s":"value"},{"t":"value"}]]}
```

I get an error parsing this so how should I build my classes?
Now I have:

```
companion object {
    class ResponseDataModel {
        @JsonProperty("s", required = true) var s: Int = 0
        @JsonProperty("v", required = true) lateinit var v: Array<SubjectsValueResponseDataModel>
    }

    class ValueResponseDataModel {
        @JsonProperty("s", required = true) lateinit var s: String
        @JsonProperty("t", required = true) lateinit var t: String
    }
}
```

Value g is ignored

```
    val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
    var respObject: DataModel.Companion.ResponseDataModel? = null
    try {
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(iStr, "UTF-8"), 8)
        val respContent = reader.readLine()
        Log.d("Response Data", respContent)
        respObject = mapper.readValue(respContent, DataModel.Companion.ResponseDataModel::class.java)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Response Data", "Error converting result " + e.toString())
    } finally {
        iStr.close()
        return respObject
    }
```

Comment: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of my_package.managers.DataModel$Companion$ValueResponseDataModel out of START_ARRAY token`

Comment: Your JSON object's `v` field is an array of arrays. Each inner array contains 3 different objects. Your Kotlin structure doesn't match this structure at all.